# Need to set text other than what we have in String[] in jcombobox

Tags: java, swing

Need to set text which is other than what we have in String[] in combo box. In need to provide read-only view where need to show the earlier selected text from combo box and which was saved in database. Now i need to read those (getProgramingByName(String)) and show it Jcombox box.

But I can see we can only set text which present in String[].
cb.setSelectedItem(lang), where lang should be part of languages. Here reason of setting text other than what we have in String[] may be source of String[] is now changed also UI is only read only purpose.

code :

```
  public class ComboxBoxDemo implements ActionListener {

JFrame f;
JLabel label;
JTextField txtField;
JButton loadBtn;
JComboBox cb;

ComboxBoxDemo() {
    String languages[] = { "C", "C++", "C#", "Java", "PHP" };
    f = new JFrame("ComboBox Example");

    txtField = new JTextField(20);
    cb = new JComboBox(languages);
    loadBtn = new JButton("Load");
    loadBtn.addActionListener(this);

    f.add(txtField);
    f.add(cb);
    f.add(loadBtn);
    f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    f.setSize(350, 350);
    f.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ComboxBoxDemo();
}

public static String getProgramingByName(String text) {
    // have the logic to get saved info
    return "Java1"; // other than what we have in String[]
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (loadBtn == e.getSource()) {
        String text = txtField.getText();
        if (text != null) {
            String lang = getProgramingByName(text);
            cb.setSelectedItem(lang);
        }
    }
}
```

}

EDITS:

```
cb.setRenderer(new ItemRenderer());

class ItemRenderer extends BasicComboBoxRenderer {
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected,
            boolean cellHasFocus) {
        super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

        System.out.println( "\n Index :"+index + " Value :"+value);
    
        String items = (String) value;

        if (index == -1) {
            setText(ComboxBoxDemo.getProgramingByName("test"));
        } else {
            setText(items);
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

After adding above when UI open's i can see Java1 is visible but when i select any item like C#, C etc it still show Java1 in combo box.
UI :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mb83J.png)

Comment: [Set the renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setRenderer(javax.swing.ListCellRenderer)) to show whatever you'd like to see

Comment: Code for in the **getProgramingByName()** method: `String val = null, v; for (int i = 0; i < cb.getItemCount(); i++) { v = cb.getItemAt(i); if (text.toLowerCase().contains(v.toLowerCase())) { val = v; break; } } return val;`.

Comment: @g00se http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Swing_How_to/JComboBox/Create_custom_JComboBox_Renderer.htm checked this example but no luck. it would be great you can provide  me some example reference.